# Setting iOS background/lockscreen image programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, jailbreak, lockscreen

I'd like to be able to set the lockscreen background image programmatically. I'm aware that this is only possible for jailbroken iOS devices.

Here are some things that I've tried:

1. Place a LockBackground.png in /private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/. This works but requires a hard respring. `notify_post("com.apple.language.changed");` doesn't work for a soft respring.
2. Use `class-dump` to dump private methods of UIKit. UIKit in 4.2 used to have a method called `+ (void)setDesktopImageData:(id)fp8;` but it appears to be missing in 4.3 and above.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Why don't you dump SpringBoard instead?

Comment: I thought I did and didn't find anything useful.. I'll try again.

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this in the SpringBoard dump which I think will be of use to you:

In SBWallpaperView.h:

```
- (void)replaceWallpaperWithImage:(id)image;
```

And in SBUIController.h:

```
- (id)wallpaperView;
```

So you can do something like:

```
[(SBWallpaperView *)[SBUIController sharedInstance] wallpaperView] replaceWallpaperWithImage:anImage];
```

That's one way.

The other one I found was to use SBWallpaperView's `+ (void)noteWallpaperPreferencesChanged;`, I'm not that sure about this one, but it seems like if you do what you did in the first thing you tried, and then use this instead of a respring, it might work.

Comment: Where did you find these header files?

Comment: I dumped the SpringBoard executable.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, would you mind accepting it and giving me the the bounty?

Comment: My bad dude,  last time I used bounties it got awarded to the highest rep question. Anyway, I've accepted your answer, hope that some consolation. I haven't had a chance to test this though :(