# Change iOS Home Screen Wallpaper Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios12, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to change the wallpaper of Home Screen and Lock Screen programmatically. I've seen many blogs and posts so far like:

1. [Setting iOS background/lockscreen image programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752202/setting-ios-background-lockscreen-image-programatically)
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreakdevelopers/comments/24uyr6/which_private_framework_and_methods_set/
3. [Cropping/zooming not working while setting iOS Wallpaper using PhotoLibrary private framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696884/cropping-zooming-not-working-while-setting-ios-wallpaper-using-photolibrary-priv)
4. [Handling private frameworks in Xcode ≥ 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000053/handling-private-frameworks-in-xcode-%E2%89%A5-7-3/37001091#37001091)
5. [How to set lock screen , wallpaper and Ringtone programmatically in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476777/how-to-set-lock-screen-wallpaper-and-ringtone-programmatically-in-iphone)

Nothing is working from all of the above. Here is what I tried so far:

```
    NSString *path;
    #if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
        path = @"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework";
    #else
        path = @"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework";
    #endif
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
        [bundle load];

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

        // Instantiate the controller.
        id class = NSClassFromString(@"PLStaticWallpaperImageViewController");
        id controller = [[class alloc] performSelector:@selector(initWithUIImage:) withObject:image];

        // Select what wallpaper mode.
        // 0 - Both lock screen and home screen.
        // 1 - Home screen only.
        // 2 - Lock screen only.
        int wallpaperMode = 0;
        [controller setValue:@(wallpaperMode) forKey:@"wallpaperMode"];

        // Tell the controller to save the data.
        [controller setValue:@YES forKey:@"isWallpaperEdit"];
        [controller setValue:@YES forKey:@"saveWallpaperData"];

        // Save the photo.
        [controller performSelector:@selector(_savePhoto) withObject:nil];
        [controller performSelector:@selector(setWallpaperForLocations:) withObject:@(wallpaperMode)];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

I know that Apple will not approve it but I don't care.

Any help is appreciated.